# Question about empty list for define while loop in python

Tags: python

```
def mergeSort(Data):
# result = []
# This location can't operate result.append(group1(pop(0)) at the while loop.

if len(Data) <= 1:
    return Data

mid = len(Data) // 2

group1 = mergeSort(Data[:mid])
group2 = mergeSort(Data[mid:])

result = []
# Why this postion?

while group1 and group2:
    if group1[0] < group2[0]:
        result.append(group1.pop(0))
    else:
        result.append(group2.pop(0))

while group1:
    result.append(group1.pop(0))
while group2:
    result.append(group2.pop(0))
return result
```

Hello. I have a doubt about this code. I defined function for making merge sorting algorithm. But the empty list for inserting values couldn't working when I input forward. I don't under reason why this list should be input in front of the while loop. please let me know.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable result as a list before you can append to it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858392/initializing-variables-in-python

Comment: It works just fine for me. You should recheck it personally @Ian. Also, make sure the indentations are right.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: First location can't operate `result.append(group1(pop(0))` because when you call function, python don't know what is `group1`? Besides, I test a case array [3, 2, 1] and your algorithm print out [1, 3, 2]. If I change array to [3, 2, 1, 4], output is right [1, 2, 3, 4].